# FPDF setSourceFile source file issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, fpdf, fpdi

Hello all I am new to codeigniter

I am using fpdf & fpdfi  for create and append pdf files.

I have some silly issue as below

when I am sending file path as

```
$pdfPath="./public/site/userdocuments/sagar/RetData/1.pdf";
$pdf -> setSourceFile($pdfPath);
```

then it works but when I am trying to make pdf files dynamic as follows

```
$filename="1.pdf";
$pdfPath="./public/site/userdocuments/sagar/RetData/".$filename;
$pdf -> setSourceFile($pdfPath);
```

then it throws error as below

> InvalidArgumentException: Cannot open
>   http://10.0.11.114:8888/start.spaceParse/public/site/userdocuments/sagar/RetData/1.pdf in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/start.spaceParse/application/libraries/pdfResources/pdf_parser.php on line 192

I had already researched on it and its related to file not found issue. I cant understand whats the problem with it.

any help appreciated ..

Thanks in advance

Sorry for bad English..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the `explode` function. Try changing your code to something like this:

```
$filename="1.pdf";
$newString= explode(".",$filename);
$pdfPath="./public/site/userdocuments/sagar/RetData/".newString[0].".pdf";
```

Comment: What's the sense of that code? It's nearly the same as writing `$pdfPath="./public/site/userdocuments/sagar/RetData/“.$filename;` as in the initial question. The code does exactly nothing useful!

Comment: right that's what i thought, but still don't know why this works and writing the name directly doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local path instead of an URI.

Your code looks like a local path but the error message "says" something different.